# How to wait for a movieclip to stop the animation in order to do other actions in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

the think is; in the main timeline im on the frame 1 (animation stoped here), i want to pass to frame 2 but first i play a MC, who is an animation of a black square who covers all the movie that goes from transparent on his own frame 1 going to full opacity in frame 5 and then transparent again in frame 9. Well i want to pass from main frame 1 to frame 2 when the MC animation is exactly on his own frame 5. Im developing in AS3, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the frame 5 of your Movie clip, place a AS to tell root timeline goto nextframe.

```
this['root'].gotoAndPlay(2);
```

Comment: Symbol 'cortina', Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 5, Line 1 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAnaPlay through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Yeah. You need to use this['root'].gotoAndPlay(2) to prevent the compile for type error.